# Can I play FIFA 15 on a Hard Drive rather than on the disc on my PS3?

Tags: ps3, fifa-15

Playing FIFA 15 on the disc sometimes results in long load times. So, I was wondering if I could put the game on the hard drive and play it from there, obviously keeping the disc in for security purposes. Will that speed up play?

Any ideas are wanted.

Comment: You can purchase FIFA 15 from the Playstation store, [example depending on your region](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-gb/games/fifa-15/cid=EP0006-NPEB02045_00-FIFA15PSNLICENSE)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have the game as a digital download, then I don't think there's any way for you to play the game outside of the physical copy.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will see the option on your game settings somewhere to "install on disc" but I don't believe Fifa has that setting.  It probably already installed some of the game on your drive but you will have to run it off the disc sadly.